# Sort the results by three sets with a subset

Tags: sql, sqlite, transactions, relational-database

```
select stampata_sn,numero_conto,dest_stampa,portata,categoria,prog_inser,nodo,desc_art,prezzo_un,quantita from comanda where contiene_variante='1' and ntav_comanda='25' and posizione='CONTO' and stato_record='ATTIVO'   and numero_conto ="1" 

                        union all

select stampata_sn,numero_conto,dest_stampa,portata,categoria,prog_inser,nodo,desc_art,prezzo_un,sum(quantita) as quantita from comanda where (contiene_variante !='1' or contiene_variante is null) and length(nodo)=3 and ntav_comanda='25' and posizione='CONTO' and stato_record='ATTIVO'  and numero_conto ="1"  group by desc_art

                        union all

select stampata_sn,numero_conto,dest_stampa,portata,categoria,prog_inser,nodo,desc_art,prezzo_un,quantita from comanda where length(nodo)=7 and ntav_comanda='25'  and posizione='CONTO' and stato_record='ATTIVO'  and numero_conto ="1"  order by nodo asc;
```

I have these three queries.

If the first query before "union all" is query A, and the second and third are B and C respectively, how can i do:

```
(A(B ORDER BY B ASC),C) ORDER BY (A,C) ASC
```

I need to do:

```
Extract A
Extract B of A (by node) AND order alphabetical in the internal
Extract C 
Then order by A (and B is an A subset),C alphabetical
```

Then the result will be for example:

```
C   Bitter
A   Coca
B   + Ice
B   + Lemon
B   + Orange juice
A   Juice
B   + Lemon
C   Orange cup
C   Spaghetti
```

Instead of a random order by node, like:

```
C   Orange cup
A   Juice
B   + Lemon
C   Bitter
A   Coca
B   + Orange juice
B   + Ice
B   + Lemon
C   Spaghetti
```

I hope I have been clear.

Comment: A/B/C behave like *tables*. What do you mean with "ORDER BY A"? Which column is used?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed with this query:

```
select  substr(desc_art,1,3)||'MA'|| substr(nodo,1,3) as ord,stampata_sn,numero_conto,dest_stampa,portata,categoria,prog_inser,nodo,desc_art,prezzo_un,quantita from comanda as c1 where contiene_variante='1' and ntav_comanda='34'  and posizione='CONTO' and stato_record='ATTIVO' and  numero_conto ="1"  
union all
select  substr(desc_art,1,3)||'MA'||substr(nodo,1,3) as ord,stampata_sn,numero_conto,dest_stampa,portata,categoria,prog_inser,nodo,desc_art,prezzo_un,sum(quantita) as quantita from comanda as c1 where (contiene_variante !='1' or contiene_variante is null) and length(nodo)=3 and ntav_comanda='34' and posizione='CONTO' and stato_record='ATTIVO'  and numero_conto ="1"   group by desc_art
union all       
select  (select substr(desc_art,1,3) from comanda where nodo=substr(c1.nodo,1,3)  and ntav_comanda='34')||'MB' ||substr(nodo,1,3) as ord,stampata_sn,numero_conto,dest_stampa,portata,categoria,prog_inser,nodo,desc_art,prezzo_un,quantita from comanda as c1 where length(nodo)=7 and substr(desc_art,1,1)='-' and ntav_comanda='34'   and posizione='CONTO' and stato_record='ATTIVO'  and numero_conto ="1"  
union all
select (select substr(desc_art,1,3) from comanda where nodo=substr(c1.nodo,1,3) and ntav_comanda='34')||'MC'||substr(nodo,1,3) as ord,stampata_sn,numero_conto,dest_stampa,portata,categoria,prog_inser,nodo,desc_art,prezzo_un,quantita from comanda as c1 where length(nodo)=7 and substr(desc_art,1,1)!='-' and ntav_comanda='34'  and posizione='CONTO' and stato_record='ATTIVO'  and numero_conto ="1"   
order by ord ASC;
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Thank you for the help.